# Dojo dnd: Avatar positioning

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop, avatar

Is it possible to change the positioning of the avatar with dojo toolkit's dnd api? At the moment, when dragging, the avatar of the dragged item appears to the right and below the mouse cursor. I want it to be in the same position as the mouse cursor. I ran some usability tests on my application, and most people seem to attempt to try and drag the avatar into the drop area, as opposed to moving the cursor over the drop area. Any input would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: For future searchers: I stumbled on this issue when trying to change the dojo.dnd.Manager OFFSET_X and OFFSET_Y values, which broke my drop targetting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, not possible for technical reasons.

UPDATE: by popular demands these are technical reasons:

- When you have a node right under the mouse, the node gets all mouse events.
- The mouse events bubble up the parent chain.
- Now imagine that you move this node with the mouse — this node would always get all mouse events.
- It means that any other node, e.g., a target cannot get mouse events unless it is a parent of the moved node. Typically this is not the case.

But I know that other people can do it! It should be possible! Yes, it is possible … in principle:

- Let's register all target nodes.
- Let's catch relevant mouse move events directly on the topmost parent (the document).
- When we detect a drag operation, let's do the following:

  1. Calculate geometry (bounding boxes) of all targets.
  2. On every mouse move lets check if the current mouse position overlaps with a target. Bonus points for an "A+" student: detect overlaps with other nodes, e.g, when a target is partially obscure for cosmetic reasons, and process this situation correctly.
  3. If the current mouse position overlaps with a target, let's initiate "drop is possible" actions, e.g., show some cues so the end user knows that she can drop now.

Why Dojo doesn't do that? For a number of technical reasons (finally we got there!):

- A node's geometry calculations are notoriously buggy in most browsers. As soon as tables are involved, or any other non-trivial means of placement, you cannot be 100% sure that the bounding box is correct.
- Geometry calculations is an expensive operation, and we have to do it at least once on every drag operation for all targets assuming that no changes can be made during the drag operation (not always the case). A browser may reflow nodes for many reasons ⇒ it can move/resize existing targets, so we have to be vigilant.
- Typically the calculated boxes are kept in a list ⇒ checking the list for intersections is O(n) (linear) ⇒ doesn't scale well as number of targets grow.
- All mouse event handlers should be fast, otherwise a browser's mouse event handling facility can be "broken" leading to unpredictable side-effects. See the previous points for reasons why mouse event processing can be slow.
- Improving on the linear search is possible, e.g., 2D spatial trees can be used, but it leads to more (much more) JavaScript code ⇒ more stuff to download on the client side ⇒ typically it isn't worth it.

How do I know that? Because Dojo used to have this kind of drag'n'drop in earlier versions, and we got sick and tired fighting problems I described above. Any improvement was an uphill battle, which increased the code size. Finally we decided against reinventing and replicating mechanisms already built in a browser. A browser does virtually the same work: calculates geometry of nodes, finds the underlying node, and dispatches a mouse move event appropriately.

The current implementation doesn't use mouse move events and do not calculate the geometry. Instead it relies on mouse over/out events detected by targets after a drag was started. It works reliably and scales well.

Another wrinkle in this story: Dojo treats targets as containers — a very common use case (shopping carts, rearranging items, editing hierarchies). Linear containers and generic trees are implemented at the moment, custom containers are possible. When dragging and dropping you can see and drop dragged items in a proper position within a target container, e.g., inserting them between existing items. Implementing this feature using geometric calculations and checks would be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: What kind of technical reasons? Any documentation you could direct me toward?

Comment: Believe it or not but that is how the official documentation starts --- explaining the underlying reasons. I am 100% sure that you read it, but just in case this is the link: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/dnd